# Part of jquery code (side-panel sliding) not working in IE8

Tags: jquery

Here is the fiddle of the problem :
http://jsfiddle.net/kLXYa/1/

when you click on 'toggle' link, the left panel squeezes to 0% width and some other actions occur, and when you click `'toggle'` again, the reverse happens. The issue is that left panel squeeze is not working on `IE8`, and i am pretty doubtful of it working in `ie9`. Please tell wheat can i do to make it work in `IE8` onwards, just like it is working in Firefox

the jquery i have made is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#panel-trigger').click(function(){

if($('#panel').is(":visible")){
$('#panel').animate({width: "0%"}, 200);
$('#rightside').animate({"width": "98%", "margin-right": "1%", "margin-top": "150px"}, 400, function(){

    $('.topmenu').fadeIn(300);

    });

}

else{

$('#panel').animate({width: "22.75%"}, 350);
$('#rightside').animate({"width": "69.25%", "margin-top": "0px"}, 150);
$('.topmenu').fadeOut(300);

}

});

});
```

Comment: What is the versio. Of the underlaying jquery? 2.X support IE9+ see: http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: only part of the script is not working, is that something related to versions?